# reference to a field inside a CompletableFuture which can again be a CompletableFuture : java

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am making call to a service, which is returning CompletableFuture.

The output structure is as follows.

```
Class Output {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
}
```

And I want to make the call to service, and want to go ahead with my execution till the name is present.

Something like,

```
CompletableFuture<Output> futureOutput = makeServiceCall(input);
String name = futureOutput.get().name;
processName(name); // which will do some costly operations and make use of the name at the end.
```

In the above approach, I need to wait till my `futureOutput` is ready, even though I need it only later.

I look for something like a below approach.

```
CompletableFuture<Output> futureOutput = makeServiceCall(input);
CompletableFuture<String> futureName = futureOutput.get().name; // This is wrong, but can we create a reference in a similar way?
processName(futureName); // which will do some costly operations and make use of the name at the end.
```

Its fine for me to change the signature of `processName` from `String` to `CompletableFuture<String>` but not to `CompletableFuture<Output>` as `Output` does not make any sense for that method.

What are the suggested ways to have a future reference which is a field of another future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Just use [`CompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApplyAsync-java.util.function.Function-)

From the JavaDoc:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed using this stage's default asynchronous execution facility, with this stage's result as the argument to the supplied function.

In your example (where `T` is the return type of the `processName` method):

```
CompletableFuture<Output> future = makeServiceCall(input);
CompletableFuture<T> result = future.thenApplyAsync(o -> processName(o.name));
```

Now, when the `makeServiceCall` `CompletableFuture` completes then another `CompletableFuture` is generated to wrap an async call to `processName` - this creates an asynchronous pipeline.

Depending on what you want to do, you might what to use [`CompletableFuture.thenAcceptAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenAcceptAsync-java.util.function.Consumer-) instead, for example if `processName` doesn't return a useful result:

```
CompletableFuture<Output> future = makeServiceCall(input);
CompletableFuture<Void> result = future.thenAcceptAsync(o -> processName(o.name));
```

You would probably also want error handling in case this processing doesn't complete, this can be done with [`CompletableFuture.exceptionally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-). This adds a callback this is invoked if the processing pipeline terminates with an `Exception`.

By means for a full example, you could do:

```
makeServiceCall(input)
    .thenApplyAsync(Output::getName)
    .thenAcceptAsync(this::processName)
    .exceptionally(e -> {
        //log the error
        System.out.printf("Oops - %s%n", e);
        //return some useful default value
        return ProcessingResult.SUCCESSFUL;
    });
```

This pipeline (while slightly contrived - there is no need to get the name async) is fully asynchronous. There is no need to block the `Thread` that creates the task any any point; the task will either complete successfully or the failure handler will be invoked.

Comment: I was mainly looking for a performance improvement, where I dont want to wait for the execution of processName(). Wait only at the point where the name is used within processName. With the help of your answer, cam up with the below approach. Please correct if I am going wrong somewhere.
`CompletableFuture<Output> futureOutput = makeServiceCall(input);`

`Future<String> futureName = futureOutput.thenApplyAsync(output -> output.name);`

 `processName(futureName); // which will do some costly operations and make use of the name at the end.`

Comment: @pks looks fine. I would take heed of the warning re error handling as if you never add an handler for errors you may get silent failure. Also note that if `processName` calls `Future.get` then all this effort is in vain as your `Thread` will simply block there and wait for completion - making the process synchronous again. You are better off with `processName` accepting a `String` and calling `thenAcceptAsync`.

Comment: @pks also note that once processing becomes asynchronous it happens on a different `Thread`. This opens up the whole thread-safety can of worms. For example if code in your async lambdas references members of their containing `class`, if these members are not `final` or `volatile` you open up visibility issues. If your async lambda, for example, adds elements to a `Collection` and that `Collection` is not thread-safe then your code will fail in wonderful and unexpected ways. Do not assume that `CompletableFuture` is a magic bullet for multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the result to a new completion stage, for example:

```
CompletableFuture<Output> futureOutput = makeServiceCall(input);
futureOutput.thenAcceptAsync(output -> processName(output.name));
```

(or using `thenAccept` if you want to block until the operation completes).